# Angular service worker : initiating network status

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I want to make my web like google spreadsheet(offline-mode), i've been able to detect the network lost. But when the connection is offline, the network status give me online status.

```
constructor() {
   window.addEventListener('online', () => //do something);
   window.addEventListener('offline', () => //do something);
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYAIl.png)

Comment: What you mean by `network status give me online status` ?

Comment: ive been uploading photos there, i mean when im online and i turn off the wifi, the tick status become offline, and service worker is working into offline mode. but when  i refresh my browser, the tick status will show online instead offline. my code only working when the network is CHANGE, how to make it know im offline or online, instead of network change?

Comment: This is expected behavior, since you are only intercepting the event and event will be triggered only when their is change in state from `offline to online` or `online to offline` . What you can do is, when status changes use a `localStorage` variable to store the change and read the change first when your application loads. So, if the application is `offline` your variable will have `offline status` after reload and same for online.